# Error: class, interface, or enum expected?

Tags: java

This is my code and i am not getting any idea how to solve this problem i have spend 5,6 hours and try everything but not able to solve a minute problem

```
JdbcEx.java
import java.sql.*;
public class JdbcEx {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:personDSN";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Database";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String add = rs.getString("address");
                String pNum = rs.getString("phoneNum");
                System.out.println(name + " " + add + " " + pNum);
            }
            con.close();
        }catch(Exception sqlEx) {
            System.out.println(sqlEx);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Is `JdbcEx.java` actually at the top of your source file?

Comment: It seems that you are an absolute beginner with Java. Do you really think the best way to learn programming ... is to start with such complicated examples? What exactly is your problem? Is your code not compiling? Is there an exception at runtime? Long story short: better start by reading same base material on how java works; then write code to understand compiler warnings and errors. Then run your programs and understand exceptions, what they mean and how to fix them. Instead of just throwing some code at strangers; hoping that they can do the **learning** for you.

Comment: @Jägermeister totally agree about difficulty of the example... but... have you checked the subject of the question? ;) it was hard for me to find out the problem also... but is there xDDD

Comment: @Radiodef **YES** as long as the problem seems to be ***error: class, interface, or enum expected***

Comment: @JordiCastilla Ah, right; I didn't get that "pun". But it just proves my point: a newbie should be studying books; and not create a new question on SO for each new compiler error he is facing.

Comment: @Jägermeister sure... i guess a `HelloWorld` could be better....

Comment: @JordiCastilla It would appear so (I'm aware), but it would be conclusive if the OP confirmed.

Comment: Friends the problem is that compiler is not compiling my code and giving this error class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: Radiodef Yes JdbcEx.java is at the top of source file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be ok. And according to the subject of the question:

> error: class, interface, or enum expected

The only problem is that your code does not starts correct you must put your package declaration in the begining:

```
JdbcEx.java
```

is wrong, this must be the name of the file... and your first line:

```
package yourPackageName;
```

**NOTE:** this is not necessary if you use default package (which is not recommended).

Comment: Sir name of the file is JdbcEx.java  so what should i write at the start of the code?

Answer (score 0):

yar package name is java.sql and package is import.  you should write:

```
import java.sql.*;
```